# Linker error while compiling Octave 4.2.1 with Intel MKL by Intel C++ Compiler

Tags: c++, c, octave, icc, intel-mkl

I was trying to compile Octave 4.2.1 with Intel MKL by Intel C++ Compiler.

According to [this article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-mkl-in-gnu-octave), my configure scripts are

```
source /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/linux/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/intel/bin
export MKLROOT=/opt/intel/mkl
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk
export CC=icc  
export CXX=icc  
export F77=ifort  
export CFLAGS="-O3 -ipo- -std=c99 -fPIC -DMKL_LP64 -DM_PI=3.1415926535897932384" 
export CPPFLAGS="-I$MKLROOT/include -I$MKLROOT/include/fftw" 
export LDFLAGS="-L$MKLROOT/lib/intel64 -L$MKLROOT/../compiler/lib/intel64" 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MKLROOT/lib/intel64:$MKLROOT/../compiler/lib/intel64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
./configure --sysconfdir=/etc --with-blas="-Wl,--start-group -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -Wl,--end-group -liomp5 -lpthread -lm" --with-lapack="-Wl,--start-group -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -Wl,--end-group -liomp5 -lpthread -lm" --with-fftw3="-Wl,--start-group -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -Wl,--end-group -liomp5 -lpthread -lm" --with-fftw3f="-Wl,--start-group -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -Wl,--end-group -liomp5 -lpthread -lm" --enable-fortran-calling-convention=gfortran
```

The configuring phase was successfull without any warning but while compiling there is a linker error

```
...
CXXLD    src/octave-cli
icc: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-Wold-style-cast'
icc: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-Wcast-align'
liboctave/.libs/liboctave.so: undefined reference to `__builtin_mul_overflow_p'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:14682: src/octave-cli] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/phqb/Downloads/octave-4.2.1'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:26135: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/phqb/Downloads/octave-4.2.1'
make: *** [Makefile:9910: all] Error 2
```

As I know the `__builtin_mul_overflow_p` macro is a GCC 7 builtin, does `icc` support this macro? Or there is any workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Octave-and-Intel-MKL-td4684897.html

Comment: I changed `CC=gcc` and `CXX=g++` then it compiled successfully. But how can I compile with `icc`?

Comment: Haven't you read the link that I gave you?

Comment: I have read the link. They suggested changing the compiler to `gcc`, didn't they?